# Fragment showing the wrong arguments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that is using viewpager and fragments with tabs. I pass data from the activity to the Fragments but it is always showing the wrong data for the specific tabs. I have one fragment which is supposed to query data depending on the arguments passed through the bundle.

```
private Fragment createFragment(String title){
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("category",title);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;

}
```

Then I pass this function on the viewpager like so:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(createFragment("Item 1"),"Tab 1");
    adapter.addFragment(createFragment("Item 2"),"Tab 2");
    adapter.addFragment(createFragment("Item 3"),"Tab 3");
    adapter.addFragment(createFragment("Item 4"),"Tab 4");
    adapter.addFragment(createFragment("Item 5"),"Tab 5");
```

Lastly I get the argument passed like so:

```
String argument = this.getArguments().getString("category");
```

the problem is when I'm on Tab 1, It returns Item 2. But when I visit all tabs, it starts to return the correct item i.e. Item 1 when on Tab 1.

Where is the problem?

EDIT:

the ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
  return  fragList.get(position);;
}
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    fragList.add(fragment);
    titleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragList.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could create the adapter class and make sure you're passing the right fragment on the right position. It might be a problem with the adapter adding the fragments on the wrong position the way you are instantiating them.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
           case 1: return createFragment("Item 1"),"Tab 1");
           case 2: return createFragment("Item 2"),"Tab 2");
           case 3: return createFragment("Item 3"),"Tab 3");
           case 4: return createFragment("Item 4"),"Tab 4");
           case 5: return createFragment("Item 5"),"Tab 5");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using 

   `@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }`

Comment: Could you post the full code of the adapter, and where you add things to the list. Maybe there is some error there.

Comment: I think it is something to do with adding to the list and using it to getCount at the same time. The Android system calls these methods at quite random times so we don't know if the getCount and getItem is called before you've added all your items... Anyway its better to hardcode the getItem position so you are 100% sure.

Comment: That seems like the only explanation considering that the same index you're switching is the same used to get the fragment at a given index. You'd expect the same result.